# How to read iOS 4 crash logs?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I'm new to iPhone, bear it with me.

My app crashes and creates a .crash file in DiagonosticReports but it hardly has any info. It doesn't tell me what is the last line of code that it executed. On digging I found [this blog](http://furbo.org/2008/08/08/symbolicatifination/) which talks about symbolification tool:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/iPhoneRemoteDevice.xcodeplugin/Contents/Resources/symbolicatecrash
```

This tool doesn't exist in the specified directory. Have things changed since iOS 3?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dragging the crash report to the Xcode Organizer (Cmd-Shift-2) should do.

(Xcode 3 keyboard shortcut was Ctrl-Cmd-O.)

Comment: To clarify, you have to drag it to the Device Logs section.

Comment: From what I can tell, dragging the file onto XCode simply opens the raw file for viewing. Also viewing a crash log in the Organizer window (from a device XCode knows about) ...also just shows a raw file. And I see no useful information there. Seeing the line of code where it crashed? Symbolification?  What's the answer to this bit of the question?

Comment: @Harry, the Organizer will automatically symbolicate the crash report if it can find the necessary files.

Answer (score 4):

Hi
You can also view your crash report by selecting the Organizer option in the window tab of XCode.Select your device and navigate to the Device Logs tab.There you can find the crash reports of all the apps from the selected device.

Cheers